# Opensearch on Django: pointing Firefox to the correct favicon and suggestions

Tags: json, django, firefox, opensearch

I'm trying to add opensearch on Django, and I can neither get Firefox to fetch the correct favicon, nor get to query and display suggestions. I also tried on Chrome and I don't think I can add localhost as a search engine.

Here's my opensearch.xml file, which is correctly read by Firefox since I can add it to my search engines. Note that it currently shows localhost URLs for debugging purposes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
    <ShortName>My website</ShortName>
    <Description>My description</Description>
    <Image width="16" height="16" type="image/x-icon">http://localhost:8000{{ STATIC_URL }}ico/favicon.ico</Image>
    <Url type="text/html" method="get" template="http://localhost:8000/articles/?q={searchTerms}" />
    <Url type="application/x-suggestions+json" method="get" template="http://localhost:8000/api/v1/articles/?q={searchTerms}"/>
    <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

#### Favicon issue

When I add my site as a search engine in Firefox, here are the requests made:

> [29/Apr/2014 18:18:19] "GET /favicon.ico/static/ico/favicon.ico/ HTTP/1.1" 200 49266
>
> [29/Apr/2014 18:18:21] "GET /opensearch.xml HTTP/1.1" 200 335
>
> [29/Apr/2014 18:18:21] "GET /favicon.ico/static/ico/favicon.ico/ HTTP/1.1" 200 49267

For what reasons does Firefox try to fetch `/favicon.ico/static/ico/favicon.ico/` if the image is set to `/static/ico/favicon.ico/`? I know that `/static/ico/favicon.ico/` is valid since it's the one we use on the website and it works well (both locally and live).

#### Suggestions

What is the JSON format accepted for opensearch? I found the RSS and ATOM formats, but not the JSON one.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

#### Favicon issue

The issue is that I have the `APPEND SLASH` setting active, and I didn't define a URL for the favicon. For *some* reason Firefox would fetch to /favicon.ico/static/ico/favicon.ico even before requesting anything to the server.

The solution for tha favicon, if you have APPEND SLASH enabled, is to add the following to your main `url.py`:

`url(r'^favicon\.ico/$', RedirectView.as_view(url=settings.STATIC_URL + 'ico/favicon.ico'), name='favicon'),`

The slash at the end of `ico` is **very** important. Without it the browser will be redirected to the main page.

#### JSON suggestion format

Link to the documentation: http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/Extensions/Suggestions

`["Search term entered by user", ["Suggestion 1", "Suggestion 2", ... ]]`